# Ops Hub Utility does not continue after one failure. It keeps stopping and refuses to continue the migration.

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I am currently migrating my project form On Prem to VSO. Using Ops Hub tool I was able to migrate upto a few thousand change sets. After one failure occurred, the tool just stopped and did not continue the migration further. Is there any way I can skip the failed item and ask the tool to move on?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please describe to us the error message of the failure. Source Control data is usually linearly dependent on it's previous changesets. Owing to that behavior, if any particular changeset fails, the subsequent changeset migration is halted.

Hence, unless that failure is fixed you wont be able to move on.

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to the TFS Integration Platform for moving source and Work Items you can do some amount of edit and continue.

If there is a failure you can:

1) perform a manual checkin and then tell the platform the checkin id that solves the issue
2) start a fresh migration from where the old one left off after you have taken some action to resolve the issue.

It really depends on the error, however I have found the TFS IP to have more flexible error/exception resolution than OpsHub.

It is however not user friendly or intuitive. That is the advantage of OpsHub for simple migrations. It's Easter...